# Animations in TableView in Ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewanimation

I have a tableview with a hidden property. I want to unhide it with animation so that it could slide from bottom to top? Any suggestions please.

```
-(IBAction) hideTable : (id) sender;
{

if(self.tb.hidden==true)
{
    self.tb.alpha=1;
[self.tb setHidden:NO];
}
else{
[self.tb setHidden:YES];
}
}
```

Comment: u want to move table view bottom to top?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-(IBAction) hideTable : (id) sender{

    if (self.sessionView.hidden == YES) {
        // Currently NOT Visible. Show it now

        // First unhide it
        yourTableView.hidden = NO;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                         animations:^{

                             // Get the Existing table View frame
                             CGRect hiddenFrame = yourTableView.frame;

                             // Reset it to 0 or your own value
                             hiddenFrame.origin.y = 0;

                             // Set the new frame
                             yourTableView.frame = hiddenFrame;


                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                             NSLog(@"Shown");
                         }];


    }
    else{
        // Currently Visible. Hide it Now

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                         animations:^{

                             // Get the Existing table View frame
                             CGRect hiddenFrame = yourTableView.frame;

                             // Under the superview height
                             hiddenFrame.origin.y = yourTableView.superview.frame.size.height;

                             // Set the new frame
                             yourTableView.frame = hiddenFrame;


                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                             yourTableView.hidden = YES;

                             NSLog(@"Hidden");
                         }];


    }



}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
     CGRect frame = self.tb.frame;
    if (self.tb.hidden) {
        CGRect temp_frame = frame;
        frame.size.height = 1;
        self.tb.frame = temp_frame;
        self.tb.hidden = NO;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                         animations:^{
                             self.tb.frame = frame;
                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         }];
    }
    else
    {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect temp_frame = frame;
                         frame.size.height = 1;
                         self.tb.frame = temp_frame;
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         self.tb.hidden = YES;
                     }];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
-(IBAction) hideTable : (id) sender;
    {

    if(self.tb.hidden==true)
    {
        self.tb.alpha=1;
        [self.tb setHidden:NO];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:.25
                         animations:^{
                         self.tb.frame = CGRectMake(0,50,320,400); // your req frame

                         }
         ];


    }
    else
    {


        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35
                     animations:^{

                         self.tb.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height+10, 320,400); // y point of yor tableview is more than view bounds so it goes down


                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){

                                 [self.tb setHidden:YES];

                     }
                ];

   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use the below methods:
1. (void)showDropDownTable:- To show tableview with top to bottom animation.
2. (void)hideDropdownTable:- To hide tableview with bottom to top animation. 


    - (IBAction)btnDropDownClicked:(id)sender 
      {
        if (checkShowHideTableView == TRUE) 
          {
           [self hideTableView];
          }
        if (self.tblDropDown.hidden)
          {
          [self showDropDownTable];
          }
       else  
          {
          [self hideDropdownTable];
          }
      }



     - (void)showDropDownTable 
       {
       [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut               animations: ^{
    _tblDropDown.frame = CGRectMake(self.tblDropDown.frame.origin.x,   self.tblDropDown.frame.origin.y, self.tblDropDown.frame.size.width, kDropdownTableHeight);
    self.tblDropDown.hidden = FALSE;
         } completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
       }];
       }

     - (void)hideDropdownTable
      {
      [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut   animations: ^{
    _tblDropDown.frame = CGRectMake(self.tblDropDown.frame.origin.x, self.tblDropDown.frame.origin.y, self.tblDropDown.frame.size.width, 0);
} completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
    self.tblDropDown.hidden = TRUE;
        }];
        }    

  Hope this can help you.
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following

```
[self.tb beginUpdates];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.1
                    options:(UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                 animations:^{
                     if(self.tb.isHidden)
                     {
                        self.tb.alpha=1;
                       [self.tb setHidden:NO];
                     }
                     else
                     {
                        self.tb.alpha=0;
                       [self.tb setHidden:YES];
                     }
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                 }];
[self.tb endUpdates];
```